# How to use python 'input' function in Windows command line?

Tags: python, windows, input, command, line

A have an app that does something in a destination that is given through the input function. How to do it to work in windows command line?
After initiation of the .py file the window with command line opens, closes and does nothing, I can't give there the input to continue the app.
I try to automate some apps through .bat files.
The .py looks like this:

```
#! python3.8.
import os  
path = input()  
os.mkdir('{}/newfolder'.format(path))
```

The batch file has command:

```
@py.exe C:\some\path\file.py %*
```

Thanks.

Comment: to get `%*` you should use `sys.argv` instead of `input()`. You can use `input()` to get data from keyboard or redirect data from file `file.py < data.txt`

Comment: did you try to run it directly in console? Maybe it displays some error message but it closes window very fast and you can't see this error.

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv` contains all the command-line arguments passed to a Python script except python executable. Even the current python file path.
using `sys.argv` your code should look like this.

```
#! python3.8.
import os
import sys

path = sys.argv[1]
os.mkdir('{}/newfolder'.format(path))
```

and `sys.argv[0]` contain the python file path, which should be `C:\some\path\file.py` in your case

[referance](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-sys-argv-in-python/) to a geeksforgeeks article.